# Django unit testing middleware error

Tags: django, unit-testing, middleware

This is my middleware -

```
class HeadersControlMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.

        response = self.get_response(request)

        response['Cache-Control'] = "no-cache"
        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.

        return response
```

and this is my unit test -

```
class TestHeadersControlMiddleware(MyAPITestCase):

    def dummy_middleware(self):
        response = Response()
        response.status_code = 200
        response.json = {"key1": "value1"}

        return response

    def test_cache_control_header_is_added(self):
        self.middleware = HeadersControlMiddleware(self.dummy_middleware())
        self.request = RequestFactory()
        self.request.META = {
            "REQUEST_METHOD": "POST",
            "HTTP_APP_VERSION": "1.0.0",
            "HTTP_USER_AGENT": "AUTOMATED TEST"
        }
        self.request.path = '/testURL/'
        self.request.session = {}

        response = self.middleware(self.request)

        print(str(response['Cache-Control']))
```

When running the test I'm getting the following error:

```
File ".../tests/test_headers_control_middleware.py", line 56, in test_cache_control_header_is_added
response = self.middleware(self.request)
File "..../api/headers_control_middleware.py", line 10, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
TypeError: 'Response' object is not callable
```

Any idea?

EDIT - 
Apparently, I returned 'Response' in 'dummy_middleware' instead of 'response' (thanks to @szymon for noticing). So I fixed that and updated the current error and question.

Comment: You have wrongly indented code

Comment: Can you add full traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dummy_middleware` method should take `request` as an argument. I would move it outside of the test case so you don't have to worry about `self`.

```
def dummy_middleware(request):
    response = Response()
    response.status_code = 200
    response.json = {"key1": "value1"}
    return response
```

Then you should initialise the middleware with `dummy_middleware`, not `dummy_middleware()` as you currently have.

```
self.middleware = HeadersControlMiddleware(dummy_middleware)
...
response = self.middleware(self.request)
```

Comment: Hey @Alasdair, I tried your suggestion. I got 'get_response() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given' so I edited it to 'HeadersControlMiddleware(get_response()). Then I got 'HttpResponse' object is not callable' for 'response = self.get_response(request)'

Comment: Oops, I made a typo in that bit of the code. It's the *method* `get_response` that you should pass. It then gets called inside the middleware by the line `response = self.get_response(request)`. Don't pass `get_response()`.

Comment: Seems like I'm missing something. RequestFactory doesn't seem to get any parameter.

Comment: I've rewritten the answer to use the `dummy_middleware` from your question. I can't see any issues apart from where you are currently calling `dummy_middleware()` instead of passing the method.

Comment: The current situation is that when passing the 'dummy_middleware' without '()' I'm getting error regarding the number of parameters passed to 'dummy_middleware', and when sending it with '()' it seems like it passes that stage, but I'm getting the 'Response object is not callable' error as mentioned in the question.

Comment: The `get_response` callable should take a request - that bit went missing from my answer when I changed it to use your `dummy_middleware` method.

Comment: Yes!! That's it. Thanks a lot.